# Proof of existence of probability distribution: Why $P((-\infty,a])=P^{*}(X^{-1}((-\infty,a]))$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, proof-explanation

So I'm looking at the proof that for a given cdf we can always find a probability distribution that corresponds to it.

In the proof they start out with the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{B}(0,1),P^*)$ where $P^*$ is the uniform distribution on $(0,1)$.

They construct the random variable $X$ as $X(t)=\text{min}\{x:F(x)\geq t\}$ and show that

$\forall a\in\mathbb{R}:X^{-1}((-\infty,a])=(-\infty,F(a)]\in\mathcal{B}(0,1)$

Now to show that $P((-\infty,a])=F(a)$ there is this one step wich I don't really understand:

$P((-\infty,a])=P^*(X^{-1}((-\infty,a]))$

On a side note, I have no knowledge of measure theory since at my university it wasn't a prequisite for taking this course on probability.

Comment: How is $P$ defined?

Comment: Oh yeah, it's the probability distribution of $X$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we have a random variable $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ (with $P^*$ been probability measure on $\Omega$). By definition, it's probability distribution is a measure $P$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $P(A) = P^*(\{t | X(t) \in A\}) = P^*(X^{-1}(A))$.

Comment: About which definition are we talking here ?

Comment: Well, you said "$P$ is the probability distribution of $X$". What does it mean?
Usually it means that we take $\mathbb{R}$ as sigma algebra support, with Borrel sigma algebra, and define measure on it such that measure of a set is probability (according to distribution on domain of $X$) of $X$ getting into it.

Comment: Oh wait, I failed really hard here! I was supposed to show that $P$ is the probability distribution of $X$ and apparently in this proof they then express it in terms of the uniform distribution $P^*$! Still thanks for taking the time!